# DEFAULT is not allowed in this context error

Tags: sql, postgresql, identifier, reserved-words, partial-index

Im trying to add an index to the database but I keep getting an error:

> `PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  DEFAULT is not allowed in this context`

After reading the documentation for hours I can't seem to fix the issue.

I'm running this:

```
"CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_uniq_service_models_default ON service_models(zone_id) WHERE default"
```

My table looks like this:

```
create_table :service_models do |t|
  t.string :name, null: false
  t.jsonb :configuration, null: false, default: "{}"
  t.boolean :default, null: false
  t.json :metadata, null: false, default: "{}"
  t.references :zone, foreign_key: true, null: false, index: { name: idx_name(:service_models, :zones) }

  t.timestamps
end
```

What I want to do is for a ServiceModel to only have 1 default for a zone.

A zone can have many ServiceModels but it can only have 1 default one.

Comment: What do you intend to do with `where default`?

Comment: Is `default` supposed to be a boolean field in the relation `service_models`? In that case you need to quote the column name in double quotes. Otherwise, I am not sure what you expect to achieve with this index definition

Comment: @Schwern Ive updated my question to answer your question.

Comment: @HaleemurAli I had a feeling that was it but I can't get the syntax right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a partial index that only includes rows where the column `"default"` is `true`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_uniq_service_models_default ON service_models(zone_id)
WHERE "default";
```

[`default` is a reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) and has to be double-quoted when used as identifier.

Better yet, don't use reserved words as identifier to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

> What I want to do is for a ServiceModel to only have 1 default for a zone.

Since you're using Rails, this may be better done with [validations](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of).

```
class ServiceModel
  belongs_to :zone

  validates_uniqueness_of :zone, conditions: -> { where(default: true) }
end
```

---

A where clause can be added to an index to create a partial index of only the rows which match. But `where default` is not a valid where clause because `default` is a SQL keyword. Since `default` is a SQL keyword it must be quoted as a column.

```
create unique index service_models_default_zone_idx
  on service_models("zone_id")
  where "default"
```

Or in your `create_table` block...

```
t.index(:zone_id, unique: true, where: '"default"')
```

Comment: Hi @Schwern I did go down that route yesterday and I ended up with the same error. Erwin just explained above that Default is a reserved word.

Comment: @joeyk16 Down which route? Validations? `where("default")` will also fail for the same reasons.

Comment: The validation works of course. The `where("default")` doesn't. I must have it on the database level.

Comment: @joeyk16 `where(default: true)` ensures Rails will quote the column name. And I've also provided both the SQL and Rails way to make the unique index.

Comment: @joeyk16 Sorry, I got the quoting wrong. I've been hanging around MySQL too much. I'm with Erwin, consider a different column name. `is_default` perhaps.